# Characterization of Convex Symmetric Balanced Sets

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $E$ be a Vector Space over $\mathbb{K}$, where $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K}= \mathbb{C}$. We say that $U\subset E$ is balanced if $\alpha U\subset U$ whenever $|\alpha|\leq 1$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb{K}$. Also, $U$ is said to be symmetric if $-U\subset U$, where $-U=\{-u:\ u\in U\}$.

When $E$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, then it is possible to show that a convex set $U$ is symmetric if and only if it is balanced. On the other hand, if we consider the complex vector space $\mathbb{C}$ and we take the set $S=\{a+bi:\ |a|\leq 1,\ |b|\leq 1\}$, we have that $S$ is convex and symmetric but $E$ is not balanced $\Big($multiply $1+i$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i$ $\Big)$.

My question: Does anyone knows some characterization of these kind of sets in complex vector spaces: Convex and Symmetric implies Balanced? I mean: necessary and sufficient conditions?

Note: Balanced always implies Symmetric.

Comment: The characterization of sets for which "convex and symmetric" implies "balanced"? Logically, these are the sets which satisfy *at least one* of the properties: (i) not convex; (ii) not symmetric; (iii) balanced. This is a rather strange class of sets, and I don't think there can be a better characterization of it than (i)-(ii)-(iii).

Comment: @5pm, can you give me an example of a Symmetric Balanced Convex set that is not the ball (in $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Anyway, I could not undertand your logic @5pm, or maybe it is my english. Because if the set satisfy i), how can it be in the required class?

Comment: There aren't other balanced sets in $\mathbb C$. Note that $\mathbb C$ is a one-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$. You should not expect to find interesting geometry in one dimension. // I was reacting to your "kind of sets in complex vector spaces: Convex and Symmetric implies Balanced". The statement "$A\implies B$" is equivalent to saying "either $A$ is false or $B$ is true". For example, the class of sets for which "convex implies bounded" consists of (i) all non-convex sets; (ii) all bounded sets.

Comment: It is true. Well, in $\mathbb{C}^2$ it is impossible to visualize such a thing, but maybe there is some geometrical intuitive set. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, the [polydisc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydisc).